# Linux zip a directory excluding some internal directories

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

I'm trying to zip the public_html folder to the exclusion of two folders, like this:

`tar -czf myzip.tar.gz  --exclude=home/mydomain/public_html/folder0 --exclude=home/zeejfl6/folder1  /home/mydomain/public_html/`

But I get the error:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

I tried a few combinations... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an *error*, it's a *warning*.

Archives containing absolute paths to files are a security risk.  Imagine an archive containing `/etc/passwd`.

---

If you insist upon having the absolute paths in the archive, use the `-P` option:

```
 -P, --absolute-names
       don't strip leading `/'s from file names
```

Comment: I'm not used to linux... would that be `tar -Pczf myzip.tar.gz --absolute-names --exclude=home/mydomain/public_html/folder0 --exclude=home/zeejfl6/folder1 /home/mydomain/public_html/`